# why openssl in osX is 1.0.2e and in local server is 0.9.8zg :(

Tags: php, openssl, server, localhost, local

Why Openssl in osX is `1.0.2e` and in local server php used `0.9.8zg`.

My question is why php on local server using old openssl version and when i use Oppenssl version in OS X Terminal it's say that openssl version is 1.0.2e ? ><

I can not install composer on my mac i tried new version of xampp and mamp 3.5 and same problem

Help.

Comment: I believe this is because PHP is bundled with own openssl library used during compilation process. It isn't dependant on openssl used globally on your mac. I can't help you more because I don't use mac.

Comment: Thanks for your time bro, I still have that problem i'm waiting for help